# How do I remove dotted border around Silverlight 4 in Firefox 4?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, firefox4

If any of you switched to Firefox 4, you'll notice a new focus visual around your silverlight object. This visual is a dotted border that surrounds the object tag whenever it gains focus. This can be very ugly when you have a Silverlight object that's part of an HTML page (ie. not 100% width/height).

So how do I get rid of this? In CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer myself. Add this line to your CSS.

```
object::-moz-focus-inner { border:0; }
```